# where can i find detailed info on parameters speed tracer considers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gwt, speedtracer

I was trying to use speed tracer for sample application developed. The info speed tracer provides seems really good but can anybody tell me where can i find more detailed documentation on params like javascript callback, dom event, paint etc. can be found. Additioanlly what params are considered for the same?

thanks

Edit:

thanks for immediate response suresh. these links were useful especially examples one. But what i wanted was list of all params with there detailed info or scenario they are applicable in order to better understand e.g. while running one my own example i got new param - 
**Program**

Below are is summary found in speed tracer

86.7% JavaScript Callback (3.45s)
7.3% UI Thread Available (288ms)
2.9% Style Recalculation (114ms)
2.2% Paint (85ms)
0.6% Layout (23ms)
0.3% Dom Event (10ms)
**0.2% Program (6ms)**

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an [video tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/)

And speed tracer with [examples tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/speed-tracer-examples) from Google.

Comment: thanks for immediate response suresh. these links were useful especially examples one. But what i wanted was list of all params with there detailed info or scenario they are applicable in order to better understand e.g. while running one my own example i got new param - 
**Program**

Below are is summary found

86.7% JavaScript Callback (3.45s)
7.3% UI Thread Available (288ms)
2.9% Style Recalculation (114ms)
2.2% Paint (85ms)
0.6% Layout (23ms)
0.3% Dom Event (10ms)
**0.2% Program (6ms)**